# Node / Mocha test times out

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js

I have some simple Promise-based code that is timing out (> 2000ms) despite my best attempts. Help?

```
export function listCurrentUserPermissions(req, res, next) {
  return UserPermission.findAll({
    where: { accountId: req.user.tenant() }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('-----------------------------------');
    console.log(error);
    console.log.bind(console);
    console.log('-----------------------------------');
  }).then((permissions) => {
    return res.json({ userPermission: permissions.map(serializeUserPermission) });
  }, next);
```

And the test:

```
  describe('GET /api/v0/permissions', () => {
    it('shows the current users permissions', () => {
      return api.listCurrentUserPermissions(req, res, next).then(() => {
        expect(UserPermission.findAll).to.have.been.calledWithMatch({
          where: { accountId: req.user.tenant() }
        });

        expect(next).to.have.beenCalled;
        expect(next.lastCall.args[0].output.payload.statusCode).to.equal(200);
        expect(next.lastCall.args[0].output.payload.permission).to.include(nonAdminPermission.permission);
      });
    });
  })
```

The error I get:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

`console.log` is never called but I can confirm that the code is called with the proper params, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `next` continuation is being passed as the error handler (second arg) of the `then` method.

I think you want:

```
export function listCurrentUserPermissions(req, res, next) {
  return UserPermission.findAll({
    where: { accountId: req.user.tenant() }
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log('-----------------------------------');
    console.log(error);
    console.log.bind(console);
    console.log('-----------------------------------');
  }).then((permissions) => {
    return res.json({ userPermission: permissions.map(serializeUserPermission) });
  }).then(next);
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same error occurs with this refactoring :(

Comment: Oh, woops. Can't pass `next` as the success callback because it's node style (error, result) and would be invoked with the results of the previous promise. Last line should be: `.then(() => { next() })`

Comment: Though you typically don't need to invoke `next` since this route is the last in the line (it's sending a response). There's no need to invoke subsequent middleware. So I usually invoke `.done` on the promise instead.

Comment: So interesting. I've tried this too. When I add `done` to the end of the Promise chain I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined` in the test.

Comment: `done` terminates the promise chain. I would have the test be operating on the returned promise *or* do the assertion once `next` is invoked. Doing both doesn't make sense to me. (The `next` callback is the trigger for when the middleware is done. So there's no need to return a promise. But your test is relying on the method returning a promise.)